# C# console and sharepoint link

Tags: c#, sharepoint, integration

this is the code use for get the data from the sharepoint site.

```
 string siteUrl = "https://sharesss.xyz.net/sites/xxx-xxx/training/Lists/";

 System.Net.NetworkCredential cred= new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "Domainname");

 ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUrl);


      context.Credentials = cred;  
            Web web = context.Web;
            context.Load(web);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
```

And the execution show error:

There is no Web named \"/sites/XXXXXX/training/Lists/_vti_bin/sites.asmx\"."}

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that web exits on the site?

Comment: how can i check that?I'm restricted to it.But I use this link in browser. then it works.

Comment: The site you provided isn't available. 
You want to make some request to it ? Or ? Please explain better your issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string siteUrl = @"https://sharesss.xyz.net/sites/xxx-xxx/training";
                System.Net.NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "Domainname");
                ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

                Web web = clientContext.Web;

                clientContext.Credentials = cred;
SharePointOnlineCredentials(  (username).ToString(), FetchPasswordFromConsole());
                List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Name Of List");
                CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='ID'/>" +
                                    "<Value Type='Number'>10</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
                ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
                clientContext.Load(web.Lists);
                clientContext.Load(oList);
                clientContext.Load(collListItem);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Changed the code like this and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line of code shall be changed to

string siteUrl = "https://sharesss.xyz.net/sites/xxx-xxx/training/";

Instead of

string siteUrl = "https://sharesss.xyz.net/sites/xxx-xxx/training/Lists/";